# How to clone a shopping cart price rule in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm having Multiple shopping cart price rules and having a lot of promotions. I want to **clone/copy the shopping cart price rule**. Is any option available in Magento 2 for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default this feature is not available.

If you want,

1. You can customize like product duplication in the product grid.
2. Otherwise there are lot of third party extension available in the marketplace you can go ahead with the extension.